Line chart rendering based on dynamic duration changes with suffixes
  prTimeToMergeChartOptions : any = comboChartOptions;

  prTimeToMergeChartsOptions(){
    this.prTimeToMergeChartOptions.scales.x.title.text = "duration"
    this.prTimeToMergeChartOptions.scales.y.title.text = "Average time taken to merge pull request"
    this.prTimeToMergeChartOptions.plugins = {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title: (data) => { 
            const date = `${this.translation.translate("developmentMetrics.date")}: ${data[0].label}`;
            return date;
          },
          label: (context: any) => {
            let tooltipLines = [];
            if (context.dataset.label.toLowerCase() !== 'average') {
              const appName = `${this.translation.translate("developmentMetrics.application")}: ${context.dataset.label}`;
              tooltipLines.push(appName);
            }
            const valueInDays = context.raw;
            let displayValue;
            if (valueInDays >= 1) {
              displayValue = `${valueInDays.toFixed(1)} days`;
            } else {
              const valueInHours = valueInDays * 24;
              if (valueInHours >= 1) {
                displayValue = `${valueInHours.toFixed(1)} hours`;
              } else {
                const valueInMinutes = valueInHours * 60;
                displayValue = `${valueInMinutes.toFixed(0)} minutes`;
              }
            }
            const yAxisLabelWithSuffix = context.dataset.label.toLowerCase() === 'average'
                                        ? "Average Time to merge"
                                        : "Time to merge";
            const changed = `${yAxisLabelWithSuffix}: ${displayValue}`;
            tooltipLines.push(changed);
            return tooltipLines;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

Want to render the chart duration of y axis along with dynamic data with suffixes like Hours, days, and Months based on maxm value present inside of it
Note :
Here context.raw have values coming as days, months and Hours as well
Example : it may come as 2.4 which might be in Days and  7 might be
in Hours and also 3 which might be in months as well
for more details please follow below link :
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pMKkneTANw6palN8XnlgfoNVqnzi7H_B/view?usp=drivesdk)
